# How to iterate over SOAP API attributes and key with same names but different values?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, soap, dataframe

I am trying to create data frames out the Exact Target SOAP API responses, but am not sure how to handle this if the response has the same name for two different values I need to create the data frame from.

This is the exact SOAP response the system is outputting:

```
(SentEvent){
   Client = 
      (ClientID){
         ID = 11111111
      }
   PartnerKey = None
   PartnerProperties[] = 
      (APIProperty){
         Name = "ListID"
         Value = "11111111"
      },
      (APIProperty){
         Name = "SubscriberID"
         Value = "11111111"
      },
   ObjectID = None
   SendID = 11111111
   SubscriberKey = "aaa@aaa"
   EventDate = 2016-03-22 12:17:53.000024
   EventType = "Sent"
   TriggeredSendDefinitionObjectID = "11111111"
   BatchID = 1
 }]
```

**my goal is to put all the attributes into a dataframe but can not figure out how to go over the values for "APIProperty" and place each of them in DataFrame like so**:

```
     APIPropertyListID            APIPropertySubscriberID
0    11111111                      111111111111
1    11111111                      111111111111
```

This is my code so far, as an example I have only done one attributes into dataframe and have tried similar methods for the "APIProperty":

```
import ET_Client
import pandas as pd



try:
    debug = False
    stubObj = ET_Client.ET_Client(False, debug)
    print '>>>SentEvents'
    getSentEvent = ET_Client.ET_SentEvent()
    getSentEvent.auth_stub = stubObj
    getResponse4 = getSentEvent.get()
    ResponseResultsSentEvent = getResponse4.results
    #print ResponseResultsSentEvent

    ClientIDSentEvents = []
    #PartnerPropertiesSubscriberID = []

    for SentEvent in ResponseResultsSentEvent:
        ClientIDSentEvents.append(str(SentEvent['Client']['ID']))

    df4 = pd.DataFrame({'ClientIDSentEvents':ClientIDSentEvents})
    print df4
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Add this line and create the list as done above for clientIDsentEvents

```
PartnerPropertiesListID.append(str(SentEvent['PartnerProperties'][0]['Value']))
```